# varible is changed after stating and initializing a new char array in C

Tags: c, sockets

- When the program runs at the  `char filePath[100]="/home/wind/software/eclipse/eclipse2/server_multiaccess/wrPro3"` , I find the
  socket number of the **child socket** which is used to communicate is **changed
  suddenly**.I wonder why?
- The result is just like the picture:
  [The result using watch in gdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOjp0.png)
- `sockM` is a head of a struct list, which I defined myself. I try to put the  child struct on the struct list.

---

```
struct Sock{
    int socket;
    short int ifMain;
    short int status;
    FILE* fp;    // Cannot be initialized here
    long int filePoint;
    char recvBuf[BUFSZ];
    char sendBuf[BUFSZ];
    char command[BUFSZ];
    unsigned long int answer;
};
struct sockListEle{
    struct Sock sock;
    struct sockListEle* last;
    struct sockListEle* next;
    struct sockListEle* head; 
    struct sockListEle* end;
    int sockNum;
};

int main(void) {
    int mainS,childS;
    struct sockaddr_in mainSock;
    int on;
    .....
    .....
    while(1){
        FD_SET(mainS,&mainRead);
        select(mainS+1,&mainRead,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
        if(FD_ISSET(mainS,&mainRead)){
            struct sockaddr_in childSock;
            .....
            struct sockListEle sockC;

            sockC.sock.ifMain=0;
            ......
            sockC.next = NULL;

            sockM.end = &sockC;
            sockM.sockNum++;
            sockC.last->next = &sockC;

            maxfdp = maxfdp > childS ? maxfdp:childS+1;
    }
    .....
    .....
    if(maxfdp > 0){
        .....
        temp = &sockM;
        do{
            temp = temp->next;
            switch(temp->sock.status){
                ....
                case LOOKFOR:
                    if(FD_ISSET(temp->sock.socket,&writeList)){
                        send(temp->sock.socket, temp->sock.sendBuf, BUFSZ, 0);
                        if(!strcmp(temp->sock.command+4, "ls")){
                            char filePath[100] =
                                "/home/wind/software/eclipse/"
                                "eclipse2/server_multiaccess/wrPro3";
                            ......
                    }
                    break;
                    ......
             }
        }while(temp->next != NULL)
     }
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Comment: Don't post images of text. Less links to such images! And Format your code properly, providing a [mcve].

Comment: When you store `&sockC`, you're storing a pointer to an object whose lifetime ends with the conditional's closing brace. Dereferencing that pointer ouside of the conditional is undefined. You need to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Have fixed it under your help

Comment: But I still don't know how to post image correctly. Can anyone help me?I still feel struggling in asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem are these three lines:

```
struct sockListEle sockC;
sockM.end = &sockC;
sockC.last->next = &sockC;
```

They are to be found all three within the same while, within the same if. So: sockC is located on the stack and reused within each loop, so all your elems in your list in the end point to one and the same sockC all the time. And if you modify it (possibly by calling accept), you modify the only visible instance for all your list elements.

Instead, you need to allocate separate memory for each socket:

```
struct sockListEle* sockC = (struct sockListEle*) malloc(sizeof(struct sockListEle));
```

and assign the pointer directly (without address-of operator &). Do not forget to free the memory as soon as you do not need it any more, else you get a memory leak.

Comment: Ｔｈａｎｋ　you ~ I fix it with your help.